# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/LocalTime at hello.HelloWorld.main while trying to run program

Tags: gradle

I am beginner of Gradle build tool. I successfully compiled the HelloWorld.java code but when trying to run it gives following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/LocalTime at
        hello.HelloWorld.main (HelloWorld.java:7)
```

My HelloWorld.java code is:

```
package hello;

import org.joda.time.LocalTime;

public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
LocalTime currentTime = new LocalTime();
System.out.println("The current local time is: " + currentTime);

Greeter greeter = new Greeter();
System.out.println("greeter.sayHello()");
  }
}
```

Greeter class is simply a class which contains sayHello() method to print "Hello World" message.

Gradle's build.gradle code is:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
 }

dependencies {
  compile "joda-time:joda-time:1.5"
}
```

Please identify the issue and reply...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've not told us how you ran your program. You realize that the joda-time jar must be in the classpath, right?

Comment: I tried to run my program through command prompt as "java -cp build/classes/main hello.HelloWorld" Yes I realized that joda-time jar is missing at runtime but during build process said jar downloaded. now where is the issue I can't find.

Comment: For the record: gradle builds your application by generating classes and a jar containing those classes. It downloads the necessary libraries to its cache to be able to build it. But to run your app, you have to explicitely add all the needed runtime libraries in the classpath, using `java -cp yourJar.jar:the/path/to/joda-time.jar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the application plugin.

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'hello.HelloWorld'
```

Then run:

```
gradle installApp
```

This will create a build/install/nameofyourapp folder. Inside this will be a bin folder containing scripts to run your application correctly.

EDIT:

Assuming your application is called my_app (this is the name of the folder the build.gradle file is under), to run the application you would enter:

Linux

```
build/install/my_app/bin/my_app
```

Windows

```
build\install\my_app\bin\my_app.bat
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it was helpful.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL.
but guide me how to run my main class through command prompt as "java -cp build/classes/main hello.HelloWorld" using java plugin?